# How to get all the console.logs using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i get all the console logs logged by my web app?
Is there anything like console.getAllLogs() that can return array or object of all the logs printed?

I tried to store all the logs in an array using `window.onerror`

```
// i used something like this, but i want to get logs whenever i want
window.onerror = function(message, file, line) {
  console.log('An error occured at line ' + line + ' of ' + file + ': ' + message);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very beginning of the script, you can overwrite `console.log` so that calls of `console.log` both log *and* save what was logged to an array, then define a function that prints everything in the array:

```js
const origConsoleLog = console.log;
const logArr = [];
console.log = (...args) => {
  origConsoleLog.apply(console, args);
  logArr.push(args);
};
const logAll = () => {
  origConsoleLog.call(console, logArr.join('\n'));
};


console.log('foo');
console.log('bar', 'baz');
logAll();
```

Comment: can i do this just for console errors printed by the chrome itself , like when an api fails or , something is undefined , can i store em as well?

Comment: Yes, you can also overwrite `console.error` just like this is overwriting `console.log`, but keep in mind that errors thrown in scripts from a different domain won't contain any useful information, they'll just have "Script error"

Comment: the array push is working fine , but `logAll` returns undefined here

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" - it works just fine. If it's not working for you, then you must've altered the code somehow

Comment: It shouldn't even *theoretically* return `undefined` - even when `logArr` is empty, it should log the empty string. (unless of course you're actually logging something whose value is `undefined`)

Comment: yes , thankyou for the answer , i tried this on console.error working fine for other errors,  but its not recording error like "Failed to load" -> its a get call